# Compiling UNIX system interface from The C programming language 2nd edition

Tags: linux, unix

Once I got into chapter 8 I found that some examples are not anymore compatible (dirent.h changed a lot, macros, structs, vars...) with my actual UNIX system version (using Kali linux,  most of the examples also works on VS in windows 10). Any suggestion how I could install some compatible version(which one) of unix system to compile and execute those examples?

Comment: well linux is not Unix actually

Comment: Perhaps one of the BSD distros is closer to the original UNIX.

Comment: tyvm, gonna try